# The set X is the complex numbers in cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

I have to check if $X\backslash\{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $X \backslash \{n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Here I am considering $X\backslash\{0\}$ and $X \backslash \{n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ in subspace topology.

Comment: My intuition says no, they are not. However, I haven't been able to come up with anything despite trying various methods such as finding different topological invariant for two spaces

Comment: Any bijection should work, no?

Comment: A terse problem statement is not usually the best way to present your Question.  I would edit it to include the title's content and your Comment, if nothing else, in the body of the Question.

Comment: @ hardmath .I agree that it would be clearer if the co-finite topology was stated in the Q, not just in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{C}$; that is, a set is open if and only if it is empty or its complement is finite. Consider the bijection from $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ to $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ given by 
$$
\phi(z) = z \quad\text{ if }\quad z \not \in \mathbb{Z},
$$ 
$$
\phi(z) = 2z \quad\text{ if }\quad z \in -\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\},
$$
$$
\phi(z) = -2n + 1\quad\text{ if }\quad z \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}
$$

Consider a subset $U$ of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{N}$. Since $\phi$ is a bijection and both $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ and $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ are infinite, the complement of $U$ is finite if and only if the complement of $\phi(U)$ is finite. That is, $U$ is open in the cofinite topology if and only if $\phi(U)$ is open in the cofinite toopology. So $\phi$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Your function is not defined for positive integer $n$, as its domain is $C-N.$

Comment: @user254665. Thanks. You're right. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking of $X$ as the complex numbers makes this seem more difficult than it really is. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two sets with the same cardinality, and let $f: X \to Y$ be a bijection. Then $f$ is a homeomorphism in the cofinite topology, because it preserves cardinality and the topology is defined in terms of cardinality. Said another way, the image of a cofinite set is cofinite, as its preimage, since the cardinality of the complement is preserved by the bijection.

Comment: Equivalently,  any subset of X (or of Y) which is not equal to X (or to Y) is closed in X (or in Y) iff it is finite. So f maps closed sets to closed sets, and non-closed sets to non-closed sets.